# Did anything happen to Acheron after the events of Aliens?

Tags: alien-franchise, aliens-1986

After the terraforming plant goes boom at the end of Aliens was that the end of the Xenomorphs on that planet or did some survive? Did the company attempt to rebuild the colony?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aftermath of Acheron is chronicled in the 2013 video game [*Aliens: Colonial Marines*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliens:_Colonial_Marines).

The Company did not attempt to rebuild the colony, but immediately after the colony fell they located the derelict ship and built a facility on the site, using the eggs aboard to breed more Aliens (including a Queen). [[Secondary source]](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Origin_Facility)